# Assiging a select command with Where clause to a variable in Snowflake procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Below is my Stored procedure, trying to use where condition in select command but getting error as `SQL compilation error: syntax error unexpected 'NAME1'. syntax error line 9 at position 25 unexpected '',''.`

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Employee_sp()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
    DECLARE
        v_Query VARCHAR;
    BEGIN
        v_Query:= ''CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE EMP_TMP AS SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_NAME IN (''NAME1'',''NAME2'',''NAME3'',''NAME4'')'';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :v_Query;
        v_RowCount := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMP_TMP);
        RETURN v_RowCount;
    END;
$$;
```

It is giving error in below statement, it is not accepting '' in where condition.
`(''NAME1'',''NAME2'',''NAME3'',''NAME4'')`

Please do suggest correct code on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Quotes are to much:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Employee_sp()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
    DECLARE
        v_Query VARCHAR;
        v_RowCount INT; -- declare a variable to hold the row count
    BEGIN
        v_Query:= 'CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE EMP_TMP AS 
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_NAME IN 
(''NAME1'',''NAME2'',''NAME3'',''NAME4'')';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :v_Query;
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_RowCount FROM EMP_TMP; -- store the row count in a variable
        RETURN v_RowCount; -- return the row count as the result of the procedure
    END;
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks John, this didnt work. still showing error for NAME1 looks like "" didnt work

Comment: I change it, in your code you have to ' on the end ''NAME4'')''; Seems that this can be the error.

Comment: Thanks John, This is working after changing double quotes to single quotes for NAME1